# adding estimatedRevenue as a parameter causes Forbidden error

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I can make the request below without the estimatedRevenue metric, but when I add the estimatedRevenue, I get this error: `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtubeAnalytics.reports.query failed with error: Forbidden`

When running this code, be sure to have YoutTubeAnalytics enabled/

```
function myFunction() {
videoID = "A VIDEO ID OF A VIDEO ON YOUR CHANNEL"
  var metrics = [
    'subscribersGained',
    'shares',
    'estimatedMinutesWatched',
    'estimatedRevenue',
    'averageViewDuration',
    'estimatedMinutesWatched',
    'views'
  ];
  var oneDayInMillis = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var today = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date(today.getTime() - oneDayInMillis);
  Logger.log(yesterday);
  today = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  // TODO: FIX THIS DATE THING
  yesterday = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  Logger.log(today);

  // https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query
  var result = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query({
    ids: 'channel==' + "MINE",
    startDate: "2015-01-01",
    endDate: today,
    metrics: metrics.join(','),
    dimensions: 'video',
    filters: 'video==' + videoID,
    sort: '-views'
  });

  //var json = JSON.parse(data);
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

I'm unsure why this is happening because none of the other metrics cause problems and I'm not sure how to give myself more permissions besides what is given by the popup window when I run the script.

Comment: @Rubén if you replace videoID with a string video ID of a video from your channel this code should work (you might also have to delete the 'estimatedRevenue', which is causing the problem).

Comment: That is not enough as `YoutTubeAnalytics` is and advanced service, so it should be enabled first (by the way, have you enabled it?). By the other hand it's not clear how are you calling the code

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my original post.

Comment: Edited, does that look right @Rubén?

Answer (score 2):

As per YouTube Analytics and Reporting API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports) for channel reports:

> Note: Estimated revenue and ad performance metrics are not currently supported for channel reports. As a result, the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly scope does not currently grant access to monetary data in those reports.

Since advanced services are [thin wrappers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#support_for_advanced_services) around their corresponding REST APIs, you won't be able to access estimated revenue from the advanced service as well.

Unless you participate in the [partner program](http://www.youtube.com/yt/creators/partner.html) and therefore use *content owner reports* (which also requires setting a `contentOwner` query parameter), there is currently no way to retreive the data.